# Howto Insert Into Table with Select and Order by using fetch first rows only with DB2

Tags: insert, db2, sql-order-by, fetch

I am using DB2 V7.2 Express-C for Windows and need to insert a certain number of rows into a table as a select from another table.
Im am not sure, if this is an issue of my old DB2 Version or if there is a general problem with my statement.
So I am looking for an alternative to it.

The task is to insert a set of ids into the table markierung, which is defined with 2 columns as

> IDUSER INTEGER not null
>   IDBILD INTEGER not null

Straight forward would be to insert all corresponding items from other tables, e.g.

```
insert into markierung 
    select distinct 
       xuser.id as userid, xbild.id as bildid   
    from 
       user xuser, bild xbild, logbook xlogbook
    where 
       xbild.id = xlogbook.oid and xuser.id = xlogbook.userid
```

This approach works fine, but I want to insert only a certain number of rows (the newest ones).
Therefore I would like to do something like this:

```
insert into markierung 
    select distinct 
       xuser.id as userid, xbild.id as bildid, xlogbook.date as date   
    from 
       user xuser, bild xbild, logbook xlogbook
    where 
       xbild.id = xlogbook.oid and xuser.id = xlogbook.userid 
  order by date desc fetch first 5 rows only;
```

First problem: I need to add the date into the selection for using with the order by
because I want to insert the 5 newest rows. But the insert allows only 2 columns so 
I changed the query

```
select userid, bildid from
(
    select distinct 
       xuser.id as userid, xbild.id as bildid, xlogbook.date as date   
    from 
       user xuser, bild xbild, logbook xlogbook
    where 
       xbild.id = xlogbook.oid and xuser.id = xlogbook.userid 
) as xxx order by date desc fetch first 5 rows only;
```

The select statement works fine
But when I try to insert the selected results into the table markierung, I get an error:
I was using this statement:

```
insert into markierung 
select userid, bildid from
(
    select distinct 
       xuser.id as userid, xbild.id as bildid, xlogbook.date as date   
    from 
       user xuser, bild xbild, logbook xlogbook
    where 
       xbild.id = xlogbook.oid and xuser.id = xlogbook.userid 
) as xxx order by date desc fetch first 5 rows only;
```

This is the error:

> SQL0104N  At "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT" unexpected Token "insert into
>   markierung select userid, ".  Possible Tokens are: "".
>   SQLSTATE=42601

Do you have an idea, how I can insert only 5 rows into markierung?
Is there an alternative way or alternate query for inserting?

Comment: Please correct: DB2 Express-C exist since version 9.1.

Comment: Try moving `order by date desc fetch first 5 rows only` _into_ the subselect.

Comment: How exactly? Can you Show sample Code ?

Comment: You are right the 7.2 was not called Express-C.

Comment: It would be interesting if the problem still exists in V9.1